# Google Analytics custom dimension and metrics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Can i create custom dimension or metric with google analytics  Management API? (Or other API...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  [Full reference for the Management API is here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/).

It doesn't include custom dimensions. Would be nice though, I agree.

The [Provisioning API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/provisioning/v3/) lets you create accounts, but that is in closed beta to AdWords partners at the moment. But however an account is created, the Management API is the one that lets you edit features such as filters at the moment, so would be where custom dimensions/metric control should also sit when available.

The [collection APIs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/) then let you send data to your custom metrics and dimensions once you have created them in the admin section of your web property.

Comment: And other analytics API can't this?

Comment: Where it would appear is the Provisioning API, which is in closed Beta at the moment.  I guess it will happen there eventually. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/provisioning/v3/

Comment: If it does appear it will probably be part of the management API along with the other write stuff.   Provisioning API is for very special cases only I think.  This would be something that normal users would want to use.

Comment: @DaImTo what I don't get from this discussion is why an API not related to dimensions and metrics should provide support to those. Please clarify.

Comment: Adding custom dimensions and metrics are related to the Account. same as adding segments, and filters. Management API is for account based stuff.  He wants to Create Custom custom dimensions and metrics via the API. Which at this time you cant.

Comment: Let me rephrase it: **Why dimensions and metrics are related to the Account?**. I can't see the connection between _Managing an account_ and _Data Reporting_.

Comment: @DaImTo agreed, I edited my answer. And carlodurso - for reporting dimensions/metrics the Reporting API works, but to change meta information such as account details and filters, the Management API is used.

Comment: @MarkeD To this end, which (custom or standard) dimension or metric would relate to the account details and filters?

Comment: @carlodurso maybe we're talking of different things, but by custom dims/metrics I mean custom data that relates to your business and that you want to appear in the GA reports https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets . They aren't related to the account details/filters, but you create them as an admin action, like you do now with say filters.

Comment: @MarkeD I don't mean to be offensive but I believe that you got it wrong. No Management or Provisioning API should provide dimensions or metrics for the very nature of their objective. If they appear in GA reports, they are accessible through the Reporting API.

Comment: @carlodurso yes, you fetch data via the Reporting API, you would create them in the Management API. The question is asking how to create them. I'm not offended :)

Answer (score 2):

On [January 23, 2015](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/changelog) the Google Analytics team released a change allowing for the creating of custom dimensions and metrics via the [Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/).

Custom dimensions and metrics in the Management API allow you to create, get, list, update and patch custom dimensions and metrics for a Google Analytics property.

It is split up into two sections of the api [Custom dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customDimensions) and [custom metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customMetrics).

Not sure what language you where using so I cant help you with any sample code. I suggest you check the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Custom Dimensions and Metrics can be created in php for sure https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

```
    $dimension = new Google_Service_Analytics_CustomDimension();
    $dimension->setName('[name]');
    $dimension->setScope('[scope]');
    $dimension->setActive(TRUE);
    $client->management_customDimensions->insert('[webPropertyId]', '[analytics-account]', $dimension);
```

"$client->management_customMetrics" can be used in a similar way for metrics.

Answer (score -1):

### Gathering Data

In order to send data Google provides [collection APIs and SDKs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/).

---

### Configuring Accounts

Google Analytics provides programmatic access and management to configuration data through the [Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/) and account creation capabilities through the [Provisioning API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/provisioning/v3/).

---

### Reading Data

Google Analytics provides a simple and powerful APIs to [retrieve report data](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/) from Google Analytics.

---

To answer the OP: you create **custom dimensions and metrics** via the collection API.

#### Dimensions: Describe data

A dimension is a descriptive attribute or characteristic of an object that can be given different values. For example, a geographic location could have dimensions called *Latitude*, *Longitude*, or *City Name*. Values for the *City Name* dimension could be *San Francisco*, *Berlin*, or *Singapore*.

*Browser*, *Exit Page*, *Screens*, and *Session Duration* are all examples of dimensions that appear by default in Google Analytics. Dimensions appear all of your reports, though you might see different ones depending on the specific report. Use them to help organize, segment, and analyze your data. In some reports, you can add and remove dimensions to see different aspects of your data.

#### Metrics: Measure data

Metrics are individual elements of a dimension that can be measured as a sum or a ratio. For example, the dimension *City* can be associated with a metric like *Population*, which would have a sum value of all the residents of the specific city.

*Screenviews*, *Page per Session*, and *Average Session Duration* are examples of metrics in Google Analytics.

---

[Dimensions vs Metrics: What’s the difference?](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2009/06/22/dimensions-metrics-difference/#sr=g&m=o&cp=or&ct=-tmc&st=(opu%20qspwjefe)&ts=1403571339)
[Definitions: Goals, Metrics, KPIs, Dimensions, Targets](http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/web-analytics-101-definitions-goals-metrics-kpis-dimensions-targets/)

Comment: Does this really answer the question he asked?

Comment: He wants to "Create" a custom dimension or metric via an API.  How exactly does your answer address "creating" a Custom dimension or metric via an API?